# Modify Website After Deployment without undeploying

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have a website hosted in "Apache Tomcat Server". I would like to edit few pages without undeploying the website (realtime). Website developed using jsp/servlet. I know that generating another .war file and redeploying the new .war file but this will make my website to be unavailable for few seconds/minutes right. Is there any solution to modify without undeploying the current website so that my website will be running always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it just is textual content, consider integrating a CMS. If you mean actual code changes, you could edit the files directly in the expanded deployment directory, but I wouldn't recommend that in the long run. If you really have a requirement of no downtime, you should consider setting up an extra instance of your server that you can switch between live. This can be done quite simple, but it can also be as complex as you wish, with clustering/session replication etc.

Comment: I'll be changing code so, is it possible to edit my page by opening from deployment directory. If so, what should I do if my website is hosted in remote server(cloud).

Comment: Is it just deployed remote, or is it installed on a cloud platform? It's not the same thing, and would affect the answer.

Comment: This is in local machine only. But i had a doubt how can we modify if website is in remote machine.

Comment: You can, if you have ssh access. But as I said, it's not a good solution in the long run.

Comment: I can edit only jsp pages after deployment but servlet files can't be edited. Is there any solution to edit servlet

Comment: You can also replace class files, but really, if you have these kind of requirements, you should do it properly in the first place.